# Automatically change def. parameter by using loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to change a definition's parameter using while loop.

First, I created a function that calculates a variable, this function requires an input that will change as the while loop holds True. I tried change the input using a "+=" command but python doesn't recognize it as a change of input in formula. Any suggestions?

```
def test(x,y,z): 

    count = 0
    while count != 12:
        x-= z
        x= x* ((1+y))
        count += 1
    return x

end= test(x,y,z)

def rerun():
    test(x,y,z)

while end> 0:
    z += 1
    rerun()
```

Please note the variable I am trying to re input into function test is "z".

Comment: You should consider passing arguments to the `rerun` function...

Comment: Is this one of those "pass by reference vs. pass by value" questions?

Comment: None of your code really works. You have global variables `x`, `y`, `z`, `end` and a local variable `balance` which are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the parameter that you want to change per iteration:

```
def test(x,y,z): 
    for i in range(12):
        x -= z
        x *= 1 + y
    return x


def main():
    gx = 1
    gy = 5
    gz = 10

    # Define a function rerun which binds gx to x, gy to y and leaves one parameter open
    def rerun(z):
        test(gx,gy,z)


    # run rerun with that one left over parameter
    for gz in range(100):
        print rerun(gz)

main()
```

You will notice I have changed some of your code, too. `end` was never defined
and `while i < 0: i += 1` is not good style in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works except for a couple of things.

You need to set `end` to the result of `rerun()`, otherwise if the `while end > 0` loop is entered, it will run forever because `end` is never changed.

You also need to return something from `rerun`.

Also, if the first `end` is negative, the final `while end > 0` loop is not entered.

You didn't specify what the initial values of `x`, `y` and `z` are.
I chose 10, 2 and 3.
Here is the output:

```
test 2922930 2 3 12
test 2125770 2 4 12
end loop 2125770 10 2 4
test 1328610 2 5 12
end loop 1328610 10 2 5
test 531450 2 6 12
end loop 531450 10 2 6
test -265710 2 7 12
end loop -265710 10 2 7
```

The amended program

```
def test(x,y,z): 
    count = 0
    while count != 12:
        x-= z
        x= x* ((1+y))
        count += 1
    print "test", x, y, z, count
    return x

x = 10
y = 2
z = 3
end= test(x,y,z)

def rerun():
    return test(x,y,z)  # return the result

while end> 0:           # loop is never entered if initial `end` is negative
    z += 1
    end = rerun()       # update `end`
    print "end loop", end, x, y, z
```